# Are there translation-specific errata for D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, errata, translations

Stemming from:

[Can a Ranger's Fighting Style be a prerequisite for the feat Two-Weapon Defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62928/can-a-rangers-fighting-style-be-a-prerequisite-for-the-feat-two-weapon-defense)

has WotC ever issued 3.5e errata against certain translations to fix translation issues?

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to prove a negative, but...

## No

At the very least, [the official 3.5 errata archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata) does not list any, nor have I heard of any. From various discussions I have been a part of, it does not seem that Wizards of the Coast had very high priority for most of the translations, and most of them appear to have been sourced out, rather than done in house. Discrepancies between the English rules and various translations are fairly common, as are simple failures to adequately explain material in a comprehensible manner.

Comment: Pre-errata, the Epic Level Handbook does specifically mention Ranger's Combat Style - regarding Perfect Two-Weapon Fighting. It is very weird, though, that WotC would never just officially come out and say, "Rangers qualify for this" as they have always stated, "Fighter can take this."